# ROS Groovy installation in linux mint 15

Tags: ros, installation, dependencies, linuxmint, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been trying to install ROS-groovy on my newly installed Linux Mint 15. I followed the instructions given in the ros-groovy installation wiki page using the `precise` packages. But everytime it shows

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies
```

and then a list of packages that cannot be installed. I have followed other questions to solve such similar problem but it doesn't help. Can anybody help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/90686/ros-groovy-installation-in-linux-mint-15/) by [soumajyoti](https://answers.ros.org/users/7741/soumajyoti/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-10-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Linux Mint 15 is based of Ubuntu 13.04 Raring. ROS Groovy only supports Ubuntu 12.04 and 12.10 (Mint 13 and 14 respectively). Either consider using ROS Hydro (which supports 13.04) or moving your system to Mint 13 or 14.

---

Originally posted by [derekjchow](https://answers.ros.org/users/2190/derekjchow/) with karma: 341 on 2013-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2